# How to create custom Authorization Attribute for GraphQL Endpoints to allow users base on their "permission" claim in access token

Tags: asp.net, graphql, authorization, hotchocolate

I'm currently working on a .NET Core project that utilizes both regular API endpoints and GraphQL endpoints using HotChocolate. I implemented the authentication for both endpoints and it working.

```
 [Authorize] // this attribute from using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
 [HttpPost("GetCountryHolidays")]
 public async Task<IList<GetCountryDetails>> GetHolidays(GetHolidaysCommand command)
 {
      return await _mediator.Send(command);
 }
```

Graphql endpoint

```
 [Authorize]  // this attribute from HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization;
 public async Task<bool> CreateUser(User Command)
 {
      await _mediator.Send(query);
      return true;
 }
```

above implementation is working.

Then I need to implement the authorization. I need to check the "permission" claim in the access token. so I have implemented a custom authorization attribute called "HasPermission" to check for permissions based on claims in the access token. This attribute works perfectly for regular API endpoints with the [Authorize] attribute, but it doesn't seem to work for GraphQL endpoints.

this is my "HasPermission"  implementation

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MySampleProject.Test.Api
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class HasPermissionAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private string[] permissions { get; set; }

        public HasPermissionAttribute(params string[] permissions)
        {
            if (permissions != null && permissions.Length > 0 && permissions.Any(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("permissions", "Permissions value is not submitted or invalid!");
            this.permissions = permissions;
        }

        
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if ((permissions != null && permissions.Length > 0) && !(permissions.Any(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))))
            {
                if (!context.HttpContext.HasPermisions(permissions))
                {
                    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class HttpContextExtension
    {
        public static bool HasPermisions(this HttpContext context, string[] permissionKeys)
        {
            if (context == null)
                return false;

            List<string> permissions = context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "permissions").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
            return permissions.Intersect(permissionKeys).Any();

        }
    }
}
```

this is how I call it with regular API endpoints

```
[HttpPost("admin")]
[HasPermission("CAN_ADMIN_ONLY")]
public bool TestAdmin()
{
   return true;
}
```

it works with regular API endpoints. However, when I use the same HasPermission attribute on a GraphQL endpoint, it doesn't seem to have any effect, and the endpoint remains accessible without any permission checks:

Is there something specific I need to do to make it work for GraphQL endpoints with HotChocolate? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.